# How to see the log information in running docker daemon?

Tags: docker

I use docker on centOS, and test docker on MAC OS X. But I want to see the log information when docker run. How to find the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The daemon on Boot2docker or CentOS should have its log in `/var/log/docker.log`.
For boot2docker, you need to be in a boot2docker session.

(this isn't always the case: On [Ubuntu, for instance, this would be different](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/705#issuecomment-19262114): `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`).

If you need to see more log, you can [start the daemon with the `-D` option](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/daemon/).

Comment: Excuse me,I use the method to create mirror, but it didn't work. Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517388/how-to-create-docker-registry-mirror-on-centos