# How to create docker registry mirror on CentOS

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I try and try to create mirror in docker-registry. I have read the tutorial in [this](http://docs.docker.com/articles/registry_mirror/). And use the way in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557384/docker-private-registry-with-mirror). I'm sure I have add variable to docker daemon. And I succeed on mac OS X. But it didn't work at all on my centOS.

I run my docker daemon using this command:

```
docker -g /opt/apps/docker/lib --insecure-registry http://10.11.150.76:5555 --registry-mirror=http://10.11.150.76:5555 -d
```

and I use this command to check docker daemon:

```
ps -ef | grep "docker"
```

It really has added to docker:

```
root      1232 30203  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 10022 -container-ip 172.17.0.22 -container-port 22
root      1322   735  0 20:57 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
root     30202     1  0 20:15 ?        00:00:00 sudo http_proxy=http://10.16.10.129:9526/ docker -g /opt/apps/docker/lib --insecure-registry http://10.11.150.76:5555 --registry-mirror=http://10.11.150.76:5555 -d
```

Then, I use this command to create mirror:

```
docker run -d -p 5555:5000 -e STORAGE_PATH=/mirror -e STANDALONE=false -e MIRROR_SOURCE=https://registry-1.docker.io -e MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX=https://index.docker.io -v /Users/v11/Documents/docker-mirror:/mirror  --restart=always --name mirror registry
```

Next,I pull the new image, for example:

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

It did't work at all, because I can't find image in my path "/Users/v11/Documents/docker-mirror". I print the mirror log information and it will show me error information:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='index.docker.io',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images (Caused by : [Errno 110] Connection timed out)

and docker log :

> INFO[0023] POST /v1.19/images/create?fromImage=hello-world%3Alatest 
>   ERRO[0027] Unable to create endpoint for http://10.11.150.76:5555/:
>   invalid registry endpoint https://10.11.150.76:5555/v0/: unable to
>   ping registry endpoint https://10.11.150.76:5555/v0/ v2 ping attempt
>   failed with error: Get https://10.11.150.76:5555/v2/: EOF  v1 ping
>   attempt failed with error: Get https://10.11.150.76:5555/v1/_ping:
>   EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an
>   unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry
>   10.11.150.76:5555` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the
>   flag; simply place the CA certificate at
>   /etc/docker/certs.d/10.11.150.76:5555/ca.crt

I really search many relevant questions to find solving. But I still have no idea about it. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: It seems like a connectivity issue, I'd remove `http://` in `--insecure-registry http://10.11.150.76:5555`. Try also to _browse_ the webservice using a web browser or a dedicated tool such as postman to make sure the service is available

Comment: @superbob I have tried to remove "http://", it still did't work

Comment: Did you try my other suggestion?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure service is available. I use browse to http://10.11.150.76:5000/v1/search , and it can show me local registry information. just port 5555 to mirror can't use.

Comment: There is something I don't understand, what is 10.11.150.76? The host IP, the container IP? Something else?

Comment: It's host IP where the mirror run. and 5555 it's mirror port.

Comment: If 10.11.150.76 is the host port, I don't understand how 10.11.150.76:5000/v1/search can work because the IP should be the container one, not the host one. I mean that 10.11.150.76:5555/v1/search and <cont_ip>:5000/v1/search, but the other way around should not.

Comment: I think I use run -p 5000:5000 to map the container port to host port, So we can using host:[port] to connect container.

Comment: Maybe it is your issue, you should use 5000 port instead of 5555, if this solves your problem, I'll write an corresponding answer

Comment: @superbob I use the command what I asked in question is : -p 5555:5000.

Comment: why I said I can access to 10.11.150.76:5000/v1/search, because I have another container using registry.

Answer (score 0):

The '--registry-mirror' flag to docker has been designed to *only* work for mirroring the official docker.io repository.   In 2015, they said the registry V2 would be made to work with the '--registry-mirror' flag, but this capability is still unavailable.