# The ENV --insecure-registry can't work as expected in docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

I'm trying to setup a private docker registry mirror using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5555:5000 -e STORAGE_PATH=/mirror -e STANDALONE=false -e MIRROR_SOURCE=https://registry-1.docker.io -e MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX=https://index.docker.io -v /Users/v11/Documents/docker-mirror:/mirror  --restart=always --name mirror registry
```

And I start docker with these variable:

```
sudo http_proxy=http://10.16.10.129:9526/ docker -g /opt/apps/docker/lib --insecure-registry=10.11.150.75:5555 --registry-mirror=http://10.11.150.75:5555 -d &
```

When I pull image, it show me error information in docker log:

> INFO[0019] POST /v1.19/images/create?fromImage=hello-world%3Alatest 
>   ERRO[0023] Unable to create endpoint for http://10.11.150.75:5555/:
>   invalid registry endpoint https://10.11.150.75:5555/v0/: unable to
>   ping registry endpoint https://10.11.150.75:5555/v0/ v2 ping attempt
>   failed with error: Get https://10.11.150.75:5555/v2/: EOF  v1 ping
>   attempt failed with error: Get https://10.11.150.75:5555/v1/_ping:
>   EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an
>   unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry
>   10.11.150.75:5555` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the
>   flag; simply place the CA certificate at
>   /etc/docker/certs.d/10.11.150.75:5555/ca.crt

I try to set "--insecure" in different way from [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/936):

```
--insecure-registry http://example.com:5555
--insecure-registry example.com:5555
--insecure-registry=example.com:5555
--insecure-registry=http://example.com:5555
```

They all failed. What drives me crazy is that everyone said just set "--insecure" is ok and I succeeded on Mac OSX. But I need to create it on CentOS and I'm sure it didn't work at all.

By the way, This is my docker version information and registry latest. I use centOS:

```
docker version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.0
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 0baf609
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create docker registry mirror on CentOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517388/how-to-create-docker-registry-mirror-on-centos)